# Insert a Variable within a WP_Query (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to get wordpress to pull an ID from a variable to use within a category query but for some reason it isn't working. It's probably something with the syntax could you just give me a helping hand.

Here is what I have...

```
$catPosts1 = new WP_Query('category=$cat1&offset=5&posts_per_page=3');
```

Basically what I want it to do is get the category ID from $cat1 (I have tested and it is entering a category id in the variable), offset the number of posts by 5 and display 3 posts linked with that category. At the moment the code is just displaying posts offset by 5.

Any ideas?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you're just sending $cat1 along as a string, the code should look like this.

```
$catPosts1 = new WP_Query('category='.$cat1.'&offset=5&posts_per_page=3');
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is showing, literally, "$cat1" in the output, you might need to switch from single quotes to double quotes to get the substitution.

That is to say, do this:

```
$catPosts1 = new WP_Query("category=$cat1&offset=5&posts_per_page=3");
```

...if you're trying to get the contents of the variable into the WP_Query call.

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes instead of single.it is simple.